# How is CyanogenMod's built-in root access different?

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access

I don't know a lot about Cyanogen but realizing Snapchat fails to detect the root in it catches my attention. Does it have a different binary than `su` for root access? What mechanisms are different which grants an app root access?

Comment: Maybe the app assumes a different location. Maybe it looks for SuperSu. Basically the problem is with how the app checks for root, rather than the root binary itself.

Comment: Remember that although CM has root access, it is disabled by default on official builds. You have to enable the Developer Options menu, then go in there and enable root access for apps.

Comment: Some apps (Liveboot, Foldermount) don't work with the Privacy Guard. You need to have the SuperSu app installed for them to work.

Answer (score 1):

Cyanogen has a different root method since version 11 upwards... It is now integrated with the stock privacy manager inside privacy guard !

I believe it doesn't recognize root for the reason that it can be disabled inside development options.

You need to manually configure it via development options, This means that snap chat wont be able to run a su or adb su / sudo command

Comment: Snapchat won't try to run `su` as far as I know but rather simply check its existence.